# Is it possible to express ordering relationship between all of the possible instances of a certain class in UML?

Tags: uml

Suppose to have the class `ComplexNumber` with the properties `real:Real`  and `imag:Real`.

Is it possible to express in UML that an total ordering relationship exists for all of the instances of the class `ComplexNumber` where for each a:ComplexNumber, b:ComplexNumber a ≤ b <-> (a.real^2 + a.img^2) ≤ (b.real^2 + b.img^2) ?

Answer (score 0):

After diving into the OCL specifications I have found the answer to my own question.

It is required to define the following operation

```
ComplexNumber::<(in a:ComplexNumber):Boolean
```

with the following OCL constraint

```
context ComplexNumber::<(in a:ComplexNumber):Boolean
   body: self.real * self.real + self.img * self.img < a.real * a.real + a.img * a.img
```